# Redirect to visited page after login WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect, authentication

I found this code here:

```
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

with this I can store the last visited URL.
For example when a user goes to a page on the site which is restricted it redirects him to the /login.php page.

After he logged in there he needs to return to the page he tried to visit before being redirect to /login.php

I found this:

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return '/echo $prev_url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

/echo $prev_url is what is being pasted behind the sites URL.
After that I don't know it anymore. Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the / an actual URL and not `/echo $prev_url`

```
function admin_default_page($prev_url) {
  $prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
  return $prev_url;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

or better still (something similar to this):

```
function admin_default_page($prev_url) {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '/wp-admin';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

You need to handle both when you have the previous page, and when you don't... incase that every happens.

Comment: I use this plugin to redirect to the login.php if you are not logged in
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ 

When I add your function it sticks on the login.php page after login in.

Comment: So are you not using the WP login itself (wp-login.php)?

Comment: That's fine, it's still wp-login.php so the filter above should be what you need for redirection after logging in through the wp login process.. <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://mijn.breedijktransport.nl/wp-login.phpp" method="post"> is the standard WordPress login form tag.

Comment: Can you check your logs to see if you get any errors when trying to log in? It could be a syntax error / missing HTTP_REFERER... error logs should help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the redirect yourself and pass it the current permalink to redirect after the user logged in.

```
function redirect($url, $status){
    if (!headers_sent()){
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $status);
    }
    exit();
}

if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    redirect(wp_login_url(get_permalink()), 302);
}
```